# How to flatten nested array of objects and create new array

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, flatten

I have a data structure as the following

```
[
   {
      "models":[
         {
            "name":"xyz",
            "options":[
               {
                  "label":"blue"
               },
               {
                  "label":"brown"
               },
            ]
         },
         {
            "name":"abc",
            "options":[
               {
                  "label":"yellow"
               }
            ]
         },
         {
            "name":"def",
            "options":[
               {
                  "label":"green"
               }
            ]
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

The end result should be an array with all of the labels and name like `xyz: blue, xyz: brown, abc: yellow, def: green`

so something like this

```
['xyz: blue', 'xyz: brown', 'abc: yellow','def: green']
```

I'm trying different approaches, one with RxJS operators and another with reduce

```
let flat = (acc, current) => {

}
models.reduce(flat, [])
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use a reduce and a map like this.

```js
const arr = [
   {
      "models":[
         {
            "name":"xyz",
            "options":[
               {
                  "label":"blue"
               },
               {
                  "label":"brown"
               },
            ]
         },
         {
            "name":"abc",
            "options":[
               {
                  "label":"yellow"
               }
            ]
         },
         {
            "name":"def",
            "options":[
               {
                  "label":"green"
               }
            ]
         }
      ]
   }
];

const result = arr[0].models.reduce(
  (acc, model) => [...acc, ...model.options.map(i => ({ [model.name]: i.label }))]
  , []
);

console.log(result);
```

If the top level array can have multiple items rather than arr[0] you would need to add another reduce feeding it's accumulator in to the second reduce as it's starting accumulator rather than the empty starting array.

```js
const arr = [
   {
      "models":[
         {
            "name":"xyz",
            "options":[
               {
                  "label":"blue"
               },
               {
                  "label":"brown"
               },
            ]
         },
         {
            "name":"abc",
            "options":[
               {
                  "label":"yellow"
               }
            ]
         },
         {
            "name":"def",
            "options":[
               {
                  "label":"green"
               }
            ]
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "models":[
         {
            "name":"ghi",
            "options":[
               {
                  "label":"gold"
               },
               {
                  "label":"pink"
               },
            ]
         }
      ]
   }
];

const result = arr.reduce(
  (acc, item) =>
    item.models.reduce(
      (acc2, model) => [...acc2, ...model.options.map((i) => ({ [model.name]: i.label }))]
      , acc
    ),
  []
);


console.log(result);
```

Not sure where RxJs comes into this question but if you are looking to transform an object like this that comes back from a http request you would pipe it into the map operator and then use this function inside the map. If you are looking to do a reduce on a stream there is a reduce operator that emits the accumulator when the source stream completes or the scan operator that emits the accumulator each time the source emits.

Answer (score 1):

Use nested calls to `flatMap()`, and in the innermost call you concatenate the model name with the option label.

```js
const data = [{
  "models": [{
      "name": "xyz",
      "options": [{
          "label": "blue"
        },
        {
          "label": "brown"
        },
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "abc",
      "options": [{
        "label": "yellow"
      }]
    },
    {
      "name": "def",
      "options": [{
        "label": "green"
      }]
    }
  ]
}];

let result = data.flatMap(d => d.models.flatMap(model => model.options.map(option => `${model.name}: ${option.label}`)));

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Interesting, I'm getting an error saying flatMap doesn't exist

Comment: What environment/version are you using? See this [compatibility table](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap#browser_compatibility)

Comment: the time complexity of this code will increase because the exist 3 loop inside the code. since you are sure that the array has an object, you can index it by array[0].models. this has no loop in it and it better that array.flatMap. @Barmar

Comment: I'm not sure that the top-level array only has one object. I assumed that was just an example, and it could be more.

Comment: well it was stated in the data as you can see that the data only has one object @Barmar

Comment: It also has 3 elements in the `models` array, do you assume that will always be true?

Comment: I generally assume that whenever an array is being used, it can be any length. There's rarely a good reason to use arrays when you're only going to have one item.

Answer (score 1):

Here is using multiple `forEach` and `destructuring`

```js
const flat = (arr, res = []) => {
  arr.forEach(({ models }) =>
    models.forEach(({ name, options }) =>
      options.forEach(({ label }) => res.push({ [name]: label }))
    )
  );
  return res;
};

const data = [
  {
    models: [
      {
        name: "xyz",
        options: [
          {
            label: "blue",
          },
          {
            label: "brown",
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        name: "abc",
        options: [
          {
            label: "yellow",
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        name: "def",
        options: [
          {
            label: "green",
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
];

console.log(flat(data));
```

Answer (score -1):

```
const response = array[0].models.reduce((initial, model) => {
  if (model.options.length === 1)
    initial.push(`${model.name}: ${model.options[0].label}`);
  else {
    model.options.forEach((option) =>
      initial.push(`${model.name}: ${option.label}`),
    );
  }
  return initial;
}, []);
console.log(response)
```

;
// there is no need if the inner option has just one object you can just access it by model.options[0].label, that why there is a check to see if it one

Comment: That is a terrible use of map, might as well use forEach rather than map in that situation. initial is the worst name for an accumulator I think you could probably use. No point for the if statement as the map iteration covers it in the case of length == 1 anyway. Everything about this answer smells bad. I would absolutely reject this in a pull request.